# Idiomatic way to do swap! or update-in using Datomic

Tags: clojure, datomic

If I'm using a Clojure atom to keep count of something (votes for example), I can do this:

```
(def votes (atom {}))

(defn vote! [candidate]
  (swap! votes update-in [candidate] (fnil inc 0)))

(vote! "Abraham Lincoln")
(vote! "Abraham Lincoln")
(vote! "Winston Churchill")

votes ;=> {"Abraham Lincoln" 2, "Winston Churchill" 2}
```

Here, `update-in` neatly transforms the value at the given key, without having to look it up first.

How can I accomplish the same in Datomic? I could do something like this...

```
(defn vote! [db candidate]
   (let [[e v] (first (q '[:find ?e ?v 
                           :in $ ?candidate 
                           :where [[?e :name ?candidate]
                                   [?e :votes ?v]] db candidate)
     (transact! conn [{:db/id e :votes (inc v)}]))
```

But it seems a bit cumbersome, having to run the query, return the value and then transact with the new value. Is there a more idiomatic way of doing this (like a `swap!` or `update-in`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To me it seems most idiomatic to record the fact of the vote, then make a count query when you want to know the total. Depending on the needs of your application, this approach supports things like checking for double votes, vote change/retraction, counts in the last 24 hours, ...

Comment: This sounds good. Could you expand on it a bit? I've been trying to do an aggregate `count` query. However, it returns nothing when there are no votes at all. I think I'm looking for the equivalent of an `OUTER JOIN`...

Comment: Suppose there's a `:vote/for` attribute of a vote entity. Then the query `[:find ?candidate (count ?vote) :where [?vote :vote/for ?candidate]]` returns a set of [candidate count] pairs for all positive vote counts. You presumably know the pool of candidates, so you can add a 0 count to the result for any unpopular candidates -- part of the attraction of Datomic is that you don't have to have all your logic in the query. (Just be sure to test your query so you know that absence of votes is the only reason not to get a pair for a candidate.)